# After updating catalog price rule , customer can't get logged in

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having a strange problem . If i update catalog price rule then on front end i can't get logged in . Page keeps on loading and after some time it shows 500 error . If i update that customer account from back end just editing and saving , it enables me to log in from front . Any idea what am i doing wrong ?

Following is the line that puts browser on load and we get 500 internal server after some time...

```
$session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
```

Comment: I have followed the code to see which lines are putting it in endless loop. I found that following lines in Mage/Sales/Model/Quote in _afterLoad function are causing this loop.
 

   `if (1 == $this->getData('trigger_recollect')) {
       
               $this->collectTotals()->save();
       
            }`

If I comment out `$this->collectTotals()->save();` it loads fine.

Comment: After reading more on forums it says that when we update catalog rules in admin, then magento set this trigger to 1 so that it calculate totals again on front end and that puts in loop as it gets too long. Like suggested on these 
 

    http://www.techytalk.info/catalog-price-rules-not-applied-creating-order-magento-admin/

and here 

    https://github.com/magespecialist/MSP_CashOnDelivery/issues/6

Can you suggest what can be the proper solution, commenting this line will have other effects as well I would think, although it currently seems to work fine.
Thanks for looking into this